# How to correctly type Parameters of generic function?

Tags: typescript, generic-type-parameters

I'm trying to assign a function's parameters to a type alias. E.g. for this function:

```js
function foo<T>(bar: T, baz: number) {}
```

I want to get the signature of its parameters. Ordinarily, I'd do this:

```js
type FooParams = Parameters<typeof foo>;
```

but the problem is that that results in a signature of `[{}, number]` which makes sense because I haven't specified what `T` is. However, then I'd expect this to work:

```js
type FooParams<T> = Parameters<typeof foo<T>>; // hopefully [T, number]
```

but it doesn't, it just results in a bunch of syntax errors.

Is it possible to correctly get the type of a generic function's parameters list?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately there is no syntax for it at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use for that `infer` keyword:

```js
type Args<T> = T extends (...args: infer I) => any ? I : never;

type R = Args<(args: number, arg: string) => number >;
// R = [number, string]
```

It means that type `I` is treat as treat as generic, but you don't have to declare it like: `let fn = <T>(arg:T): T {...`

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Args%3CT%3E%20%3D%20T%20extends%20(...args%3A%20infer%20I)%20%3D%3E%20any%20%3F%20I%20%3A%20never%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20R%20%3D%20Args%3C(args%3A%20number%2C%20arg%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20number%20%3E%3B%0D%0Atype%20R1%20%3D%20Args%3C()%20%3D%3E%20number%20%3E%3B), [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

---

You can achieve generic types but you have to declare type of function:

```js
type Foo<T> = (bar: T, baz: number) => void;
type R2<Placeholder> = Args<Foo<Placeholder>>; // [Placeholder, number]
type R3 = R2<boolean> // [boolean, number]
```

Comment: This doesn't work for generic functions, only non-generic.

Comment: Exactly. I'm looking for something that works on generic functions.

Comment: This is a partial solution because you can't infer it directly from `typeof foo` but probably as good as I'm going to get for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**My solution is only a workaround which might help. This is not exactly what you want**

Here you have non generic solution.I mean it works only with `foo` type signature

```js
function foo<T>(bar: T, baz: number) { }

type Fn = (...args: any) => any
type Tail<T extends any[]> = T extends [infer _, ...infer Rest] ? Rest : never

type ReplaceFirstParameter<F extends Fn, Fst> =
    (fst: Fst, ...args: Tail<Parameters<F>>) => ReturnType<F>

type Foo<T> = ReplaceFirstParameter<typeof foo, T>

type Result = ReplaceFirstParameter<typeof foo, number> // (fst: number, baz: number) => void
```

This solution is most more generic. It will replace all `unknown` params with provided generic argument.

**I assume that every function generic is unknown - this is the weak place.**

```js
type MapPredicate<T, V> = T extends unknown ? V : T

type ReplaceUnknown<
    Arr extends Array<unknown>,
    Value,
    Result extends Array<unknown> = []
    > = Arr extends []
    ? []
    : Arr extends [infer H]
    ? [...Result, MapPredicate<H, Value>]
    : Arr extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail]
    ? ReplaceUnknown<[...Tail], Value, [...Result, MapPredicate<Head, Value>]>
    : Readonly<Result>;

function foo<T>(bar: T, baz: number) { }

type Fn = (...args: any) => any

type ReplaceParameters<F extends Fn, Value> =
    (...args: ReplaceUnknown<Parameters<F>, Value>) => ReturnType<F>


type Result = ReplaceParameters<typeof foo, number> // (fst: number, baz: number) => void
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghmACgJwgEwJYGM7AgHgBUAaKANQD4oBeKQqCADzwDs0BnKAVxYGsWA9gHcWUAPzkoALjoBYAFALQkKACUIYADZwsEAKp9BI-AqhmoAQWTIGzCG05XkcEPh79hLCsVPmycTS4IH3lzNQh2Lk1gW1YOS2sXN0NPKloAbQBdXzM0hJsmOM4snPEoEtDzGSdY%203j0jBYAMwgbAAlsyrMJdIA6fvVI6NJ4JFRMHDx8NtJ-QIgKTrDq61qHcsaW9og4NFJ%203s3WujgMTSXzCXUtHX0U4z7%20wlPz2YCg0kfewajgEYQUOhsLgCG0dntyO8FpkKKUZOpdgIWJpXD9ohQANwKBRNHhYYAYJFQJoCARECgACgARnBkDISFAaQAvGQsLgAWyprQAlFAAN5QAC%202PkymgADFRLQKQdaQBzdgyOAsEC86hUZUgEVi8I3XSIWlwdkQPDIdj4cVreKSt7zNKlGX9eWK3XaXQGDzGA3OY2m83i7yQu1qqjqYBcZAsQjgAgBkVKGPhIYxWjXN0Qb1Gk2tc1igRNYmk0hszmtKgAenLUApTXYwFZHK5yFIzIbpeQIagADcBBg0CKgA)